# Why did Google stop indexing pages from our sitemap.xml?

Tags: google, sitemap

We're seeing some pages that exist in our `sitemap.xml` but are inexplicably missing from Google's public search index.

You can't download https://superuser.com/sitemap.xml -- we protect this file because there have been issues with it in the past -- but googlebot can. We have verified via Google Webmaster Tools that the `sitemap.xml` file was pulled down today and is rated OK with no errors (green checkmark).

[image]

The `sitemap.xml` contains a list of the last 50,000 questions on our site that were asked. For example, this question ...

https://superuser.com/questions/201610/how-to-see-the-end-of-a-long-chain-of-symbolic-links

... exists in the `sitemap.xml` as ...

```
<url>
<loc>https://superuser.com/questions/201610/how-to-see-the-end-of-a-long-chain-of-symbolic-links</loc>
<lastmod>2010-10-20</lastmod>
<changefreq>daily</changefreq>
<priority>0.2</priority>
</url>
```

Searching for ["How to see the end of a long chain of symbolic links"](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=How+to+see+the+end+of+a+long+chain+of+symbolic+links) gives only one result to questionhub.com which is scraping our data (a whole different problem).

You can increment the question count number and do an exact search for the question title and you will see this pattern persist.

These urls are *in* sitemap.xml but they are not showing up in Google's index -- and yet they show up on sites that scrape our creative commons data. Why would that be?

Comment: You could always ask in the google webmaster central forums. http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Webmasters?hl=en

Comment: Something is definitely wrong.  THIS question is already indexed in Google, yet the linked question on superuser STILL does not show up in the index.

Comment: Jeff might think about just asking Matt Cutts. I've seen them talking to each other a few times on Twitter. He's usually pretty willing to help.

Comment: @Virtuosi he did, but Matt just pointed to the first answer, which doesn't fully answer the question.

Comment: FWIW We're currently seeing some issues with indexing of new content on some sites. There's a thread in our Help Forums at http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Webmasters/thread?tid=7908355c3d1637e8&hl=en about this. The URL that you mentioned appears to be affected. I imagine this will be resolved shortly, but have no fix timeframe available. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: @john excellent, thank you for the speedy followup! "Google is broken" was so far off our list of possibilities that I would feel crazy suggesting it :/

Comment: It looks like this is resolved now :-). I tried a few of the new questions from the site and they were all indexed. Woot!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It looks like Google was having some technical crawl problems this week, that sound *remarkably* like what we were experiencing:

http://searchengineland.com/is-google-broken-sites-big-small-seeing-indexing-problems-53701

> No one seems to be immune from a Google indexing problem that has many site owners baffled. Blogs and websites, big and small, aren’t being indexed as quickly as they normally are — if they’re being indexed at all.
>
> ...
>
> John from Google replied to the thread in the Webmaster forums saying:
>
> > Just to be clear, the issues from this thread, which I have reviewed in detail, are not due to changes in our policies or changes in our algorithms; **they are due to a technical issue on our side that will be visibly resolved as soon as possible** (it may take up to a few days to be visible for all sites though)

Answer (score 7):

Google doesn't make any offer or guarantee that pages in a sitemap will be indexed.

My experience has been that a page has to be linked-to (from a page of some authority) to show up.  Is that page/question linked to directly/indirectly from a page with some authority?

E.g. if the superuser.com homepage (which presumably has many inlinks) linked directly to this question, or linked to it indirectly through a number of other pages, then you could expect it to be indexed.

From google:

> Google doesn't guarantee that we'll
>   crawl or index all of your URLs.
>   However, we use the data in your
>   Sitemap to learn about your site's
>   structure, which will allow us to
>   improve our crawler schedule and do a
>   better job crawling your site in the
>   future. In most cases, webmasters will
>   benefit from Sitemap submission, and
>   in no case will you be penalized for
>   it.

http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=156184

Comment: Superuser should have sufficient links and PR to get those pages indexed with or without a sitemap. And minor pages get listed all the time. In fact they make up the majority of the index. I suspect something else is the culprit.

Comment: Agreed, the site has lots of PR and inlinks.  But, is there a chance that the page in question doesn't have inlinks?  If superuser.com (by chance) doesn't link to the page, then what does that tell google? it says the page is not important.

Comment: The page was definitely linked from the front page, and continues to be linked by from a number of other pages.  SE sites are very cross-link heavy.

Comment: Not trying to argue, but can you point out a couple pages that link to it?  I've checked a handful of pages about symbolic links and none of them link to it.

Comment: It'd be nice to have a tool to see the link structure of a big site like this.  E.g. to confirm how many pages away from the main page this particular page is.  You can imagine that if its not connected to the main page, or if its too far away, then google would be less likely to index it.

Comment: at one point yesterday one of my hits for a test question was the superuser.com homepage -- with the target URL visible on it, even in the Google cache! And yet the question itself was not indexed. Very odd.

Comment: That is odd!  Side question: are the stack exchange sites designed at all to ensure that the most relevant/popular/useful questions are linked to the most and therefore given most weight by google?

Comment: absolutely -- click on the HOT tab on the home page, or the WEEKLY or MONTHLY tab. Right there..

Comment: Matt Cutts says this is correct http://twitter.com/mattcutts/status/28060170763 but I still don't understand why a) the scrapers linking normally to this question and b) the homepage linking to this question wouldn't be enough to trigger inclusion in the index.

Comment: Agreed, it should be indexed. But, as I'm sure you know, dealing with Google's index is not a precise science, and if they're indexing ~46k of a site's 50k sitemap pages, they don't want to give the impression that they give out answers to "why isn't X indexed". rather, they'd like to handwave and say we make no guarantees :)

Comment: @Jeff: look at it this way: Google has to index the page(s) with the link to that question before it indexes the question itself. Plus it almost certainly orders the "stack" of things to index by what it deems most important (e.g. by number of links to that page).

Comment: Also re QuestionHub (funny, I just stumbled across this site looking for something else) -- QH has roughly the same traffic as SuperUser according to alexa, so it's easily possible for scraped content appearing on QH to be indexed before SU. You'll find the opposite is true in many cases too.

Answer (score 3):

I think google might be having a hard time indexing your web pages, 50.000 is alot. So my suggestion would be breakdown your sitemap into pieces like so

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sitemapindex xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
   <sitemap>
      <loc>http://www.example.com/sitemap1.xml.gz</loc>
      <lastmod>2004-10-01T18:23:17+00:00</lastmod>
   </sitemap>
   <sitemap>
      <loc>http://www.example.com/sitemap2.xml.gz</loc>
      <lastmod>2005-01-01</lastmod>
   </sitemap>
</sitemapindex>
```

If you breakdown you will have a better luck of having those 50.000 urls indexed.

Sitemaps.org explanation of the issue

> You can provide multiple Sitemap files, but each Sitemap file that you provide must have no more than 50,000 URLs and must be no larger than 10MB (10,485,760 bytes). If you would like, you may compress your Sitemap files using gzip to reduce your bandwidth requirement; however the sitemap file once uncompressed must be no larger than 10MB. If you want to list more than 50,000 URLs, you must create multiple Sitemap files.
>
> If you do provide multiple Sitemaps, you should then list each Sitemap file in a Sitemap index file. Sitemap index files may not list more than 50,000 Sitemaps and must be no larger than 10MB (10,485,760 bytes) and can be compressed. You can have more than one Sitemap index file. The XML format of a Sitemap index file is very similar to the XML format of a Sitemap file.

http://sitemaps.org/protocol.php

Comment: Sitemaps with 50,000 pages are very common. In fact someone recently posted a screenshot from their webmaster account showing Google having indexed almost all 50,000 of those pages. And I suspect superuser is more more popular (e.g. has better link popularity) than that other site.

Comment: "You have more than 50,000 URLs to list. That's the maximum that one Sitemap can include." http://sitemaps.blogspot.com/2005/08/using-sitemap-index-files.html

Comment: If you have a sitemap for each day those never change after the day is over, so that sitemap doesn't have to be accsessed again, they can crawl the links that they already indexed for changes, so google doesn't have to go trough 50,000 urls ever day to see which are old and which are new.

Comment: @sevki the oldest 50,001th question by ACTIVITY DATE (new answers, edits, etc bump this date) will not be in the sitemap. Bear in mind that superuser has only 55k questions in total.

Comment: @Jeff but SO.com has 1,014,782 and 964,782 isn't in a sitemap so google or bing doesn't know when they were last modified.. doesn't that increace your crawls. anyways I don't want to be annoying just trying to help out, I sent you an email with some more details.

Comment: What @Sevki says makes sense to me. You'd be better off keeping one smaller sitemap of more recent content (maybe 10,000) and moving all older questions into their own, static sitemaps. Daily sitemaps is overkill but monthly or bimonthly could work, or simply groups of up to 50,000. Also, Googlebot can index RSS feeds so submit your feed of recent questions.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that Google is stating that 46,514 submitted links *are* in the index. Could it be an issue with (I hate to say it) but page ranking? The scraping sites may be doing a better job cross-linking etc and being ranked higher. Just a thought.

This search [site:superuser.com How to see the end of a long chain of symbolic links](http://www.google.ca/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=%22How+to+see+the+end+of+a+long+chain+of+symbolic+links%22&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&redir_esc=&ei=v5XATOXmG4GongfaxYTgCQ#sclient=psy&hl=en&client=safari&rls=en&q=site%3Asuperuser.com+How+to+see+the+end+of+a+long+chain+of+symbolic+links&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=site%3asuperuser.com+How+to+see+the+end+of+a+long+chain+of+symbolic+links&gs_rfai=&pbx=1&fp=aa3e8f73442aae25) also appears to be fetching your sitemap.xml correctly, albeit not returning the expected results.

Comment: That scraping site gives attribute to superuser.com as the original author (although they could be more explicit about it) so Google should know they are the content's original author and give them precedence over the scraping sites.

Comment: @john correct, we require attribution with follow, as documented on http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/defending-attribution-required/

Comment: that cached sitemap is "as it appeared on 17 Oct 2010 05:40:35 GMT", 4 days ago as of the time I am writing this, so it doesn't have a lot. I spot checked a few URLs in that cached sitemap.xml and they do exist as question pages in google as well.

Comment: @john can you give an example of how they give the attribution. Thx

Comment: @Greg, Just look for the superuser logo

Answer (score 2):

With this type of thing there are a lot of potential answers.

I'd start by asking how many pages you actually have. (you submitted 50,000 URLs a quick site:superuser.com show 125,000 indexed do you think you only have 50K URLs and are submitting all of them yet Google is finding 2-3 copies of each page? or maybe you have 1Mil URLs and only 12.5% are getting indexed) getting the big picture helps to direct where to look for issues.

If nothing seems wrong with step one, I'd move onto content, it looks like QH has a whole lot more content on their page and link out many other "resources" despite the fact that all their content is scraped it's possible Google considers their page more useful since they provide more resources/information to the user. If they are considered the authority and all your content is the same as theirs it's possible Google won't index yours even though you are the original.

If you're convinced that is not the issue build some high quality links to it, blog this question on some popular employee blogs or ask some friends to blog about it, perhaps if you have SEO friends that run popular blogs they'd write a case study about it etc.

If you get a lot of strong links and it's still not getting indexed look for reasons it might be penalized (in most cases this won't be the issue but it never hurts to check).

If none of this works then 9 times out of 10 it's a simple technical issue that's been overlooked (robots exclusion or something similar).

If you're still have no answer after going through this ask Google and hope they get you an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The question was just asked yesterday - give googlebot a chance, you aren't the only site on the Internet that he has to crawl ya know :)

If questions are normally indexed within a day or so, and a week goes by and that one still isn't indexed, then I might be concerned.  But certainly not after 1 day.

Comment: They usually appear within an hour.  So I agree, I should give it time, but relative to its usual frequency... I have.

Comment: @michael make sure you're comparing apples to apples though -- Google seems to index stackoverflow.com at a MUCH higher rate than our other sites.